# Word for "held up well over time"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the quality of something "holding up well over time"?

For example, some blockbusters from years past have special effects that are still fairly good when compared to today's movies.

I would also consider the term when referring to classical works such as Shakespeare, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on whether it is a physical item or not, you might look at ***durable*** and ***enduring*** respectively.  Things like Shakespeare can also be said to have a ***lasting*** effect on the culture.

Comment: When speaking of physical objects, we often say "durable". Like, "This car has lasted me for 20 years because it was built to be durable." I've never heard that word used for something like a book or movie that has survived the test of time. "Enduring" is commonly used there.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to such films and other art works as [*classic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classic?show=0&t=1350051323):

> a : serving as a standard of excellence : of recognized value
>   b : traditional, enduring

For example, "*Blade Runner* is a classic sci-fi film."

Comment: +1 for good taste in films, but the OP already used 'classic'! ~ "I would also consider the term when referring to classical works such as Shakespeare"

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

> *[wears well](http://thesaurus.com/browse/wears+well)*
>   *[holds up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hold+up)*
>   *[has legs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+legs)*

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, for art or literature, "enduring" or "classic" or even "enduring classic" works well.

For tangible objects, "well-used" conveys the idea.

Comment: While well used has the word 'well' in it, the word 'used' is not necessarily a compliment. Time-tested also works.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, for intangibles, my absolute favorite (though not a single word) is _time-honored_.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that something like that is "timeless".